# StackTrace alternative for runtime projects in windows store applications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

With the help of StackTrace class i used to log all the information regarding the the app run to a text file in the isolated storage.

But StackTrace doesn't seem to be present in the System.Diagnostics namespace for runtime projects.

Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: What do you mean by runtime projects?

Comment: @user3373870 I think the OP must mean when the application is running on a Release build.

Comment: @golldy - what specifically are you having problems achieving? Is it saving text to a file? Getting full stack information?

Answer (score 4):

Can you throw an exception and check the StackTrace on the exception?

Comment: Somehow, after checking that it seems like the `StackTrace` in an `Exception` shows up rather short and with that information it might be better to simply write some logging method that takes parameters with attributes like `CallerFilePathAttribute`, `CallerLineNumberAttribute` or `CallerMemberNameAttribute`. In fact that's what I sometimes use in my toolkit - check [`DC.TraceLocalized()` here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging/WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging.Shared/DebugConsoleOverlay.cs)

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to write debug information in Release build, then you can use Trace instead of Debug. Unline Debug, Traces don't get ignored in Release Build [MSDN link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788)

Comment: What has that got to do with StackTrace?

Comment: @FilipSkakun,Op question reads as "i used to log **all** the information regarding the the app run to a text file." 
My Assumption was OP was using Debug.Write to log his application process, as you may know Debug statements get ignored when the project is deployed using Release Mode. I am guessing we both understood op question in different ways.

Comment: Right. OP was asking about [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) though which is for collecting stack information.

Comment: To make things clearer, i was debugging and logging using stacktrace in the silverlight project.